# Processes display not allowing page down

Tags: bash

The display hangs on one page after I invoke process through command `top`,
Press 'space', 'arrow' take no effects.
I got recommend to use `htop`, but find it complicated to manipulate.
[image]

How to page `top` command down?

Comment: Your post doesn't make sense. If you need help using the process, read the man pages. `man top`. If you can't find that, while in the terminal and `top` is running, hit `shift ?` get the information page. If `htop` was  too complicated to manipulate, you need more CLI experience.

Comment: `top -u` is to page down